# Reading data from PostgreSQL backup directory

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, linux

Let's say I have a backup directory containing PostgreSQL data from some other system. By default, the data is stored at `/var/lib/postgresql`. After changing the default data directory to the path of the backup directory by editing `/etc/postgresql/<version>/main/postgresql.conf`, I'm able to identify all the users present in the backup PostgreSQL instance.

However, I'm unsure how to access the data stored in all the databases and tables for different users without knowing the password for each user. Is there any way to retrieve the data without requiring the password for each user?

I'm able to identify all the users within the backup PostgreSQL instance, but I'm uncertain about how to determine the databases and tables associated with each user and access their respective data.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `pg_hba.conf` and add this line on top:

```
local  all all  trust
```

After reloading the server, you should be able to establish a local (domain socket) connection without entering a password. To avoid any permission problems, you can use a superuser to connect. There usually is a superuser with the name `postgres`.